# Entity Framework recursive Relations and Attaching errors

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, logic

I am creating an Application to manage Projects, Employees and assign Employees to Projects using WPF and EF 6.2.0.

So I've got an `Employee` entity with different properties (some of which are references to other entities), and I got a `Project` entity with different propeties (again, some of which are other entities).

This is my database scheme:

[image: My Database Scheme]

Now I want to create a `Job` entity which is assigned to an `Employee` and a `Project`. 
So to add one, I have to attach the whole `Employee` and `Project` entities (**including** all their referenced entities) to my context before I can add the Job right?

If I don't do that or forget one of the entity's relations/properties, it's trying to create that whole entity on the database, and throws some error like the primary key for that employee already exists (obviously, because it shouldn't create it but rather attach the existing local one)

On the other side if I do try to attach it, it fails upon attaching the `Project` because (now comes the crazy part) the `Project.CostCentre.Location.CostCentres[0].Projects[0].Contact` (`Employee`) is already attached. It is trying to attach every single thing recursively including all Lists?!

That's the stack trace that causes this:

```
private void Attach(Job job, bool attachEntity = true)
{
    Attach(job.Employee);
    Attach(job.Project); // Calls next func
    if (attachEntity && !Attached(job))
        Context.Jobs.Attach(job);
}

private void Attach(Project project, bool attachEntity = true)
{
    Attach(project.Contact);
    Attach(project.CostCentre); // Calls next func
    Attach(project.CostType);
    Attach(project.Status);
    if (attachEntity && !Attached(project))
        Context.Projects.Attach(project);
}

private void Attach(CostCentre costCentre, bool attachEntity = true)
{
    Attach(costCentre.Location); // Calls next func
    if (attachEntity && !Attached(costCentre))
        Context.CostCentres.Attach(costCentre);
}

private void Attach(Location location, bool attachEntity = true)
{
    if (attachEntity && !Attached(location))
        Context.Locations.Attach(location); // The error (that code tries to attach location.CostCentres[0].Projects[0].Contact aswell, which is an already attached Employee!!)
}
```

The full error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Attaching an entity of type 'ForecastLibrary.Employee' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.
This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values.
This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values.
In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.'
```

The full source code is here: https://pastebin.com/8YU0xQUC

I am already trying to solve this obscure error for some weeks, I hope someone here can help me out successfully adding this `Job`.

EDIT: Here's the code calling all of this:

```
// DataService::Add Function
public void Add(Job job)
{
    Attach(job, false);
    Context.Jobs.Add(job);
}

// UI Add job snippet
using (var service = new DataService(Session.ConnectionString))
{
    service.Add(JobToAdd);
    await service.SaveAsync();
}
```

Comment: It is trying to add the employee. Did you load the employee from db in the same context instance? You can tell the context that it already exists by `context.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Unchanged` and it will not add it. However, that is more like fixing your own design error so a better approach is to figure out why EF thinks this is q new entity.

Comment: Why are you attaching entities manually? EF attaches all children automatically, so you are doing something wrong outside of the posted code

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes I did load the Employee from another Context. So what you are saying is I don't need any of the attaching and only need to put `context.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Unchanged` before the Job adding?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto How does it automatically attach? Can you explain further?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto see my edit. I'm doing nothing weird i think

Comment: @CodingYoshi With setting to Unchanged I still get that error... https://imgur.com/a/UK7eY

Comment: *including all their referenced entities* -- No, only Employee and Project.

Comment: Most likely you have added a project with the same `ProjectId` to the context already so that is why you are getting the error. Take a couple of hours to read some tutorials on EF instead of trying different things. I think it will be faster if you did that and you will know exactly what the issue is.

Comment: `Context.Jobs.Add` will set the `State = Added`. It is important you know these rules because the order matters. Also I am not sure why your are loading the whole object graph. Maybe you need the whole graph but if you do not then there is no point. Also you can tell EF to include foreign key as properties in your class and then you would not need to include the navigations all the time--the graph will be lighter.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I am loading the whole Project/Employee because if I don't, some property (reference) is set to null, and then EF tries to add this entity to the Projects/Employees because it thinks that's a new one..

Comment: @CodingYoshi Can you give me an example code snippet on how my Job Add function should look like?

Comment: @GertArnold Okay, so I add my Job like this: `Context.Projects.Attach(job.Project); Context.Employees.Attach(job.Employee); job.Project.Jobs.Add(job);`, which throws this DbUpdateException upon SaveChanges: `Entities in 'ForecastModelContainer.Projects' participate in the 'ProjectStatus' relationship. 0 related 'Status' were found. 1 'Status' is expected.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using Eager loading if you know exactly what you need and have bigger data models.

Call `Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` in the constructor of you `DataService` and use `.Include` wherever you need a navigation property.

Then you need to use `Find` instead of `Attach`.

So your Job Add function could look this:

```
public void Add(Job job)
{
    var employee = Context.Employees.Find(job.Employee.Id);
    var project = Context.Projects.Find(job.Project.Id);
    Context.Jobs.Add(new Job { Employee = employee, Project = project, Time = job.Time });
}
```